# creating binary tree not binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I want to create a binary tree which fills from left to right.
i.e. if 1,2,3 are to be inserted then the tree should look like

```
   1
 /   \
2     3
```

I wrote an insert function, to insert the nodes in the tree. For the first node everything works okay..But, for the next node's (if I want to insert 4,5 as children to 2 and later 6,7 as children to 3) how should I switch between the parents (2,3)?

Here's my insert function

```
struct node * Insert(struct node * node, int data) {
if(node == NULL)
    return (newNode(data));
else {
    if(!node->left)
        node->left = Insert(node->left,data);
    if(!node->right)
        node->right = Insert(node->right,data);
    //can't figure out the condition when they both fail
}
}
```

Comment: do you have a copy of the art of computer programming? or just a college cs book that has some graph theory? this is just very basic stuff

Comment: What you're looking for is called `complete binary tree`.

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: Useful keyword: Width-first tree construction.

Comment: @keshlam make that breadth-first and it might even be useful :)

Comment: Point granted, @AlexM. Unfortunately, I didn't get back to it in time to edit.

Comment: @GradyPlayer a clue please?

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you're *not* doing this with an array. Each child of some node at some arbitrary index `n` can be found at left: `2n+1` and right: `2(n+1)`. It would make your insertion trivial, since all you're doing is tacking nodes on to the end of a sequence, resizing it as needed. Btw, this is commonly how binary *heaps* are maintained for, among other reasons, the simplicity of their indexing algorithms. Unrelated: `struct node * node` an interesting, if not self-cryptic, choice of parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node **InsertPoint(struct node **node, int *level){
    if(*node == NULL)
        return node;

    int left_level, right_level;
    struct node **left_node, **right_node;
    left_level = right_level = *level + 1;
    left_node  = InsertPoint(&(*node)->left,  &left_level );
    right_node = InsertPoint(&(*node)->right, &right_level);
    if(left_level <= right_level){
        *level = left_level;
        return left_node;
    } else {
        *level = right_level;
        return right_node;
    }
}

struct node *Insert(struct node *node, int data) {
    struct node **np;
    int level = 0;
    np = InsertPoint(&node, &level);
    *np = newNode(data);
    return node;
}
```